StoreKit showManageSubscriptions no subscriptions
I'm currently testing our app uploaded to TestFlight. I'm using StoreKit.AppStore.showManageSubscriptions to show the list of subscriptions that the user can cancel.
However, upon calling StoreKit.AppStore.showManageSubscriptions, it says "You do not have any subscriptions.".

When I test using a simulator, the subscriptions are showing. Is there something that I'm missing?

AppStore.showManageSubscriptions doesn't show the available subscriptions, it only shows options (upgrade/downgrade/cancel) for already purchased subscriptions.
You first have to subscribe by purchasing a subscription;
try await product.purchase(options: ...)

Once purchased it should show up when calling;
AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: ...)

